# I would like to develop an English gentleman vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

Can someone please provide me a list of words that could be associated with the stereotype of an Englishman who lived in the past, like "grimalkin", "forfend", "purveyor", and also give me an idea on where I could find texts that can be used for me to learn such kind of vocabulary?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic for this forum.  Also, how far in the past? English of Shakespeare time you can get from his writing. He made it so. But English extends over a good many centuries, and changed substantially over that time. Maybe Chaucer's English is what you want?

Comment: Chaucer's English is incomprehensible, no 9ne alive speaks it. The OP should look at 19th century English authors such as  Oscar Wilde, Emily Bronte etc.

Comment: Incomprehensible was too strong a word to describe Chaucer's works, it is understandable but it is written in an  English that no one speaks today.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is also quite difficult to read and understand unless you are trained in it. I remember a schoolteacher taking us through the prologue, at about age 14. It was quite a headache. But some of the modern translations, such as that by Nevill Coghill are a great deal of fun - especially the rude bits.

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be about "learning English".  The historical aspects of English are discussed on [English.se].  You can also just read lots of seventeenth and eighteenth century novels to pick it up.  However I've voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

Questions for which the answer is a list of things are not well suited to Stack Exchange (though they're not specifically against the rules of English Language Learners). But I'll suggest that you don't really want a list of words. Using language convincingly means more than *having* a vocabulary; it means knowing which word to use in which situation and why. I think the best thing you can do is read a lot of authentic period dialogue and writing from the kind of person you want to imitate.

You've already gotten the good advice to focus on one time period, since language changes. A 19th-century English gentleman talks very differently than an 18th-century one. Let's say, for that you have the Victorian period in mind. You could read a lot of works of Charles Dickens—but be careful; he includes not only gentlemen, but colorful characters of every part of society.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a particular period of time. One possibility is the Victorian era, 1837 - 1901.

Here is a list of words from the poetry of Edgar Allan Poe

> Victorian Literature
> Dustin H. (PA)
> Taken from a list of words found in the poetry of Poe.
>
> https://www.vocabulary.com/lists/143077

Comment: That's an interesting list of words. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Forfend* and *purveyor* were in use for centuries. *Grimalkin* belonged to one of the witches in Macbeth but I don't think it entered common parlance.

The period matters.

What on earth do you mean by "the stereotype of an Englishman?!"

Depending on the period...

You could have a look at Sheridan's plays. For example, [The Rivals](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/24761/pg24761.html) (1775), where the mid-Georgian nobility and their servants speak like this:

> He looks plaguy gruff
>  Egad, Ma'am, He has a pretty wit
>  O fie,
> Uncle!
>  Now - prithee -
>  Efaith, Ma'am
>  brought to Bed of a
> fine Boy and Girl
>  But depend on't your Brother is utterly
> undone
>  Odds my Life
>  Ha! ha! 'twas devilish entertaining to be
> sure

Or Trollope's novels, for example [Orley Farm](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/23000) (1861) and [Ayala's Angel](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/33500) (1878), where Victorian country gentlemen who *ride to hounds* speak like this:

> A man who could 'andle a 'orse wonderful, though he didn't know 'ow to
> ride to 'ounds;
>  By-the-by, Miss Furnival
>  Upon my word she is a
> very clever girl. And uncommonly handsome.
> Capital fun to see a turkey twice as big as it ought to be!
> Uncommonly grand!
>  Uncommonly so.
>  I ain't afeard to die.
> Snengkeld, my old pal, hand us the brandy.
>  Rather groggy on his
> pins the next morning

Or [The Novels and Plays of Saki](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.149119/page/n5/mode/2up) (1920's), where well heeled Edwardians speak like this:

> awfully provoking!
>  frightfully absorbing!
>   You utterly odious
> fablemonger!
>  I’m game!
>  That’s the worst of you middle-aged
> folks, if I may say so without offence.
> You’re so jolly well
> content to wait for things to happen.
>  But, bless my soul, we can’t
> compel Trevor to marry
>  The mater and he used to be rather
> chummy
>  It’s going awfully flat
>  Oh, a frightful fizzle

Comment: I was seeking for a kind of author that has sort of archaic and imperious language, in which his works are absurd and grotesque, just like a stereotypical German fable would be. I have the impression the Germans were used to make grotesque works. I want an author that uses archaic words like the ones found on King James Bible and old English.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the kind of author I want to find. It can be work as well. 

"
Oh my servants, these peasants are harrying my nerves. Please take them out of my castle.
Yes, our revered majesty, purveyor of wisdom.
Majesty: Now go forfend the walls of the castle
Your decree shall be fulfilled, master
Majesty: Bestow me with abundant fruits through thy peasant's labor.
And so the peasants arrived at the farms in order to cull the food of the most refined quality in order for them to furnish the ravenous regal."

Comment: It misses grotesque elements however, like sages and gnomes. I would like to find works with such a "German" characteristic.

Comment: That fake English stuff - "harrying my nerves", "forfend the walls", "ravenous regal" etc. - exists mostly in Marvel comics. What on earth is a stereotypical German fable!? Name one! Grimms' Fairy Tales (the early version, before references to eyes being pecked out etc were removed to make them child-friendly) are [here](https://www.bartleby.com/17/2/).

Comment: You say you "_want an author that uses archaic words like the ones found on King James Bible_". That will be **Shakespeare!** He and the Bible-translators were working at about the same time. Macbeth is probably the best of his plays for the kind of words you're looking for.

Comment: You really don't want Old English: it looks like this: Gif þú eart feorwitgeorn Eald Englisc ætíewþ ðus, (as it says at [Ye Olde Butchered English](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YeOldeButcheredeEnglishe): a site you might find useful). You could also copy words from [this](http://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/PR-SEL-00003-00231/7) translated and modernised-but-not-too-much edition of Beowulf. A lot of the words _come from_ Old English.